# Printing arbitrarily sized arrays inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am really at my wits end here :)

I am basically trying to set up a struct Foo which contains an array of undetermined size, then have separate fuctions set the value of the said array and print it. I keep getting 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)' and 'Use of uninitialised value of size 8' error in valgrind when I try to print, however.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Foo {
    char *name; 
    int x;
    int y;
    int *array; //this is the problematic array
};

struct Foo *foo_maker(char *name, int x, int y, int array_size)
{
    int array[array_size];
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array)); //initializing the array here, so why am i getting the errors? 


    struct Foo *a_foo = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo) + sizeof(array));

    a_foo->name = name;
    a_foo->x = x;
    a_foo->y = y;   
    a_foo->array = array;

    return a_foo;
}

void set_foo(struct Foo *a_foo, int array_size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        a_foo->array[i] =  1;
} 

void print_foo(struct Foo *a_foo, int array_size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", a_foo->array[i]);
}


void foo_killer(struct Foo *a_foo)
{
    free(a_foo);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *name = argv[1];
    int x = atoi(argv[2]);
    int y = atoi(argv[3]);
    int array_size = atoi(argv[4]);

    struct Foo *foo = foo_maker(name, x, y, array_size);
    set_foo(foo, array_size);   
    print_foo(foo, array_size);
    foo_killer(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't think it is a problem with passing a_foo->array as a parameter to other fuctions, since it is only when I try to print the array when I get uninitialized errors. I even tried printing the array inside foo_maker and set_foo, and both times I got the same error.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int array[array_size];
```

this memory resides on the local function stack and ceases to exist once the function returns.

```
a_foo->array = array;
```

will be a pointer to a memory area you no longer own, once `foo_maker()` is done.

As you allocate the array memory though when allocating a_foo, you might want:

```
a_foo->array = a_foo + 1;
```

which is kinda unusual pointer arithmetic, but will lead to a_foo->array pointing to the memory after a_foo.

It would be more understandable though if you do:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);
struct Foo *a_foo = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
a_foo->array = array;
```

Comment: thank you! 
so if I used malloc to set up the array, and then assigned it to a_foo->array, would that work? I am confused because I thought the point of using 'a_foo->array' notation was that I could assign values to it and it would stick even when outside of stacks, since 'a_foo->array' points to an area in heap?

Comment: You can also look at `calloc` which is tailor-made for initializing the blocks of memory allocated to `0`. In array situations this prevents an inadvertent attempt to read from an uninitialized value.

Comment: You need to distinguish the memory of the 4 bytes of the pointer `int * array` in `struct foo` and the memory the pointer points to. The pointer value, the memory from _where you point to_ the other memory, will stick outside the function. But the memory area you _point at_ ceases to exist, because the memory area is part of the function stack if you just do int array[array_size];

Comment: @drunkenlollipop, there is a basic misunderstanding here: "_since 'a_foo->array' points to an area in heap_": the __notation__ does not place the memory on the heap. Only memory allocated with `malloc` is on the heap!